# How to upgrade a gwt 2.5.1 based application to gwt 2.7.0?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

How can I migrate my project's GWT version from 2.5.1 to 2.7 and gxt from 3.0.0 to 3.1.1 easily? Already I tried updating the jar and the dependency but the widgets like Dialog,comboBox are having some differences in both these versions. Eg. getHideButton(),getButtonById are no longer a method of these classes which used to be in the old version of gxt. I need to update gxt because GWT 2.7 superdev mode is not suppored by gxt 3.0.0. Manually updating with the alternative solution for those methods (as per release doc) is very tedious. Please suggest the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion - you could use "Facade" pattern and retrofit all uses of `Dialog` and `ComboBox` to `MyDialog` and `MyComboBox`. Then override getHideButton() and after migrating to 2.7.0 write your own code. But really, if you're using any modern IDE it is tedious, but quite easy to spot compile errors and make necessary changes. I hope that you are using Maven or similar to manage your dependencies.

Hopefully this compatibility chart could help you deciding what versions of JARs you need to match - https://plus.google.com/+BrandonDonnelson/posts/QWfmDndSdzo